# Create options for <select> with steps, based on Max value by Query

Tags: jquery

I need to create 2 selects (price range) with options like this

```
<select id="price1">
  <option selected="selected" value="0">0</option>
  <option value="100">100</option>
  <option value="200">200</option>
  <option value="300">300</option>
  <option value="400">400</option>
  <option value="500">500</option>
  <option value="600">600</option>
  <option value="700">700</option>
  <option value="800">800</option>
  <option value="900">900</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>   
</select>

<select id="price2">
  <option value="100">100</option>
  <option value="200">200</option>
  <option value="300">300</option>
  <option value="400">400</option>
  <option value="500">500</option>
  <option value="600">600</option>
  <option value="700">700</option>
  <option value="800">800</option>
  <option value="900">900</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="1000">1000</option>
</select>
```

So I manually created these selects, but in some categories I have items with maximum price = 300, and in some with 1200.

I can get maximum price variable (from Database), and I want to create selects (both) only limited with maximum available option.

For example if:

```
$(function() {
    var vallmax = 300;
});
```

Expected output:

```
<select id="price1">
<option selected="selected" value="0">0</option>
<option value="100">100</option>
<option value="200">200</option>
```

And

```
<select id="price2">
<option value="100">100</option>
<option value="200">200</option>
<option selected="selected" value="300">300</option>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter and hide your option based upon your database value(vallmax) .

```js
var vallmax = 300; // Get max value from datatbase 
var opt1 = vallmax - 100;
$('#price1 option').filter(function() {
  return parseInt(this.value, 10) > opt1;
}).hide();
$('#price2 option').filter(function() {
  return parseInt(this.value, 10) > vallmax;
}).hide();
$('#price2').val(vallmax); //Select default max value for second dropdown
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="price1">
  <option selected="selected" value="0">0</option>
  <option value="100">100</option>
  <option value="200">200</option>
  <option value="300">300</option>
  <option value="400">400</option>
  <option value="500">500</option>
  <option value="600">600</option>
  <option value="700">700</option>
  <option value="800">800</option>
  <option value="900">900</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
</select>
<select id="price2">
  <option value="100">100</option>
  <option value="200">200</option>
  <option value="300">300</option>
  <option value="400">400</option>
  <option value="500">500</option>
  <option value="600">600</option>
  <option value="700">700</option>
  <option value="800">800</option>
  <option value="900">900</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="1000">1000</option>
</select>
```